# How to Share a Single GPU Among Multiple VMs with Parsec Connectivity?

Tags: windows-10, virtualization, nvidia-graphics-card, hyper-v, nvidia-quadro

I've managed to set up my HP Z4G4 workstation tower so that multiple guest VMs can share a single Quadro P4000 GPU. This was achieved by utilizing the scripts from the “[Easy GPU PV” project found on Github](https://github.com/jamesstringerparsec/Easy-GPU-PV), enabling me to establish Parsec connections to each machine simultaneously.

However, I'm facing an issue where the resolution of these guest VMs is locked at “1920 x 1080”, and only on rare occasions am I able to increase it to 4k. My system runs on Windows 10 22H2.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem or has suggestions on how to resolve this resolution limitation?

Comment: What virtualizing App do you use?  Are you sure it is being shared?  Numerous virtual Apps do not do this.

Comment: On which occasions are you able to increase to 4k ?

Comment: @harrymc hard to tell, usually randomly, but my observations tell me it happens a) when I remote to the machines simultaneously or when I use Hyper-V "connect to machine", I tried to install the latest version of Parsec Virtual Display Driver, then one in one guest I can manually adjust the resolution to 4k but then after a bit of use and reboots, it's back to 1920 max.

Comment: @John I use Parsec: https://parsec.app

Comment: [parsec-vdd](https://github.com/nomi-san/parsec-vdd) might relate to the problem : "This project demonstrates a standalone solution to create virtual displays by using Parsec VDD, without relying on the Parsec app". Have a look also at [Parsec vs Moonlight](https://airgpu.com/blog/parsec-vs-moonlight/).